# Club two queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query

```
 SELECT Registration.FName,RequestPooja.RitualId AS RitualId FROM RequestPooja INNER JOIN Registration
 ON RequestPooja.UserId = Registration.Id   WHERE Registration.Id=2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Registration.FName,AaparaKarma.RitualId AS RitualId  FROM AaparaKarma INNER JOIN Registration
 ON AaparaKarma.UserId = Registration.Id  
 WHERE Registration.Id=2
```

which yields the result as

```
FName   RitualId
Shreyas 24
Shreyas 37
Shreyas 37
Shreyas 37
```

Now I have a Rituals Table

```
SELECT Rituals.Id,Rituals.Name FROM Rituals
```

which will give output as

```
 Id    Name
 24    ABC
 37    xyz
```

Now i want to club these two queries and i want the desired result as

```
 FName  RitualId    Name
 Shreyas    24     ABC
 Shreyas    37     xyz
 Shreyas    37     xyz  
 Shreyas    37     xyz
```

Should i use joins or inner query to get the desired results.? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This.
Use Join because its gives you faster performance.

```
SELECT Registration.FName,RequestPooja.RitualId AS RitualId ,Rituals.Name 
FROM RequestPooja 
INNER JOIN Registration  ON RequestPooja.UserId = Registration.Id   
INNER JOIN Rituals ON  Rituals.Id=RequestPooja.RitualId
WHERE Registration.Id=2

UNION ALL

 SELECT Registration.FName,AaparaKarma.RitualId AS RitualId  ,Rituals.Name 
 FROM AaparaKarma 
 INNER JOIN Registration  ON AaparaKarma.UserId = Registration.Id  
 INNER JOIN Rituals ON  Rituals.Id=AaparaKarma.RitualId
 WHERE Registration.Id=2
```